# Having trouble getting labels to appear next to pie chart legend in a Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm fairly new to Java, and using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1.

Problem:
I'm trying to finish up a Java applet I've been working on that requires a pie chart.  I've implemented the pie chart, but I've not been able to get the text labels to appear next to the data in the legend.  Does anyone have any pointers?

```
package piechartapplet;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class PieChartApplet extends JApplet {

    int TotalPieChartSlices = 7;
    SliceValues[] pieSlice = new SliceValues[TotalPieChartSlices];
    private int pieChartValueY;

    public PieChartApplet() 
    {
//Source for input statisctics:
//Global Issues. (2012). World Military Spending. Retrieved from http://www.globalissues.org/article/75/world-military-spending             
// Link:  http://www.globalissues.org/article/75/world-military-spending

    pieSlice[0] = new SliceValues(41.0, Color.RED,"United States");
    pieSlice[1] = new SliceValues(8.2, Color.CYAN,"China");
    pieSlice[2] = new SliceValues(4.1, Color.GREEN,"Russia");
    pieSlice[3] = new SliceValues(3.6, Color.BLUE,"UK");
    pieSlice[4] = new SliceValues(3.6, Color.PINK,"France");
    pieSlice[5] = new SliceValues(21.3, Color.ORANGE,"Next 10 Countries Combined");
    pieSlice[6] = new SliceValues(18.2, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,"Rest of the World");

}

// drawing the pir chart using the values in the array
    public int drawPieChartValues(Graphics2D graphics, Rectangle pieChartArea, SliceValues[] pieSlice)
    {
    // setting font size/style
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24);
        graphics.setFont(font);
// Title of Pie Chart
        graphics.drawString("World Military Spending (% by Country)", 20, 20);
        graphics.setFont(font);
// establishing inital area positioning
        pieChartArea.x=10;
        pieChartArea.y = 30;
// using the array values, rectangles, and color to draw the slices
        for(int i=0; i<pieSlice.length;i++)
        {
            graphics. setColor(pieSlice[i].getSliceColor());
            graphics.fillRect(pieChartArea.x, pieChartArea.y, 15, 10);
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            pieChartArea.y+=20;
            graphics.drawString(""+pieSlice[i].getSliceValue(), pieChartArea.x+25, pieChartArea.y-10);
        }
        return pieChartArea.y+=10;
    }

//The code below was adapted from an example I found that enables me to pull from
// the array and use the values as the slice sizes, putting them into a 360* pie
// Walker, K. (2012). How to Draw a Pie Chart in Java. Retrieved from http://www.ehow.com/how_6647263_draw-pie-chart-java.html 


    public void drawPieChart(Graphics2D graphics, Rectangle pieChartArea, SliceValues[] pieSlice) {

// pulling array data for the individual slices
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i<pieSlice.length; i++) 
        {
            total += pieSlice[i].getSliceValue(); //pulling value
        }
    // drawing the slice and positioning it accordingly
        double slice = 0.0D;
        int StartAngle = 0;
        pieChartArea.x = 20;
        for (int i=0; i<pieSlice.length; i++) {

// finding initial and final angels
            StartAngle = (int)(slice * 360 / total);
            int finalAngle = (int)(pieSlice[i].getSliceValue() * 360 / total);
//loop for last slice
            if (i == pieSlice.length-1) 
                        {
                finalAngle = 360 - StartAngle;
            }
// Pulling color from array and setting accordingly
        graphics.setColor(pieSlice[i].getSliceColor()); //pulling color
        // drawing pie piece
                graphics.fillArc(pieChartArea.x, pieChartValueY, pieChartArea.width/2, pieChartArea.height/2, StartAngle, finalAngle);

        slice += pieSlice[i].getSliceValue();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        pieChartValueY  = drawPieChartValues((Graphics2D)g, getBounds(), pieSlice);
        drawPieChart((Graphics2D)g, getBounds(), pieSlice);
    }   

    public void init() {        
// Sizing my applet
        setSize(600,600);
// adding applet to pane
        getContentPane().add(new PieChartApplet());
    }
}
```

**Here is the 'values' code**

```
package piechartapplet;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SliceValues 
{
// Establishing values for the pir chart

    private double Slicevalue;
    private Color Slicecolor;
    private String Slicestring;

// Construction begins...
    public SliceValues(double value, Color color, String string) {
        this.Slicevalue = value; //values from array
        this.Slicecolor = color; //color from array
        this.Slicestring = string; //string values
    }

// calling slice values, colors, strings, and setting values, colors, strings for each slice
    public double getSliceValue() {
        return Slicevalue;
    }

    public void setSliceValue(double value) {
        this.Slicevalue = value;
    }

    public Color getSliceColor() {
        return Slicecolor;
    }

    public void setSliceColor(Color color) {
        this.Slicecolor = color;
    }

    public String getSliceString() {
        return Slicestring;
    }

    public void setSliceString(String string) {
        this.Slicestring = string;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is [tag:jfreechart] permitted?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It's not prohibited, that I know.

Comment: 1) By 'label' DYM `String` or `JLabel`? 2) *"not been able to get the text labels to appear next to the data"*  Where do they appear?

Comment: The text does not appear.  I'm trying to get the associated country text to appear next to the corresponding color in the legend..

Comment: That is to say, they text at the end of my array is not appearing.  I'm doing something stupid, I know it.

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html#line.60) for [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html), illustrated [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) with labels, is included in the distribution.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  I'm supposed to build the chart from the array.  I'll keep the suggestion provided for future work though.  Many thanks.

Comment: Right, you'd have to implement your own version of [`createDataset()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html#line.81).

Comment: Something is screwy.. I'm unable to import org.jfree libraries... tells me they don't exist.

Comment: You need to add `JFreeChart` and `JCommon` to your project in NetBeans.